# How do I save a time from Bootstrap DateTimePicker as a DateTime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datetimepicker

Grabbing the date from the field returns the result:

```
04/28/2014 1:59 AM
```

I need this to be in a DateTime format - is there any option in DateTimePicker to convert it (it's not listed in the documentation if there is), or is there an option in JavaScript to easily change this into a format like:

```
2014-04-28 01:59:00.000000
```

This is the proper format for the DateTime field in MySQL.

Comment: What is `00.000000` is for?

Comment: It's just the way MySQL saves it. Look at any DateTime in a datebase and it throws that on the end for milliseconds I suppose. Being that specific isn't necessary, I don't think; it can end after the 00 for seconds.

Comment: MySQL valid datetime is `2014-04-28 01:59:00` there is no leading zeros (milliseconds).

Comment: Okay, either way I'm still stuck trying to get it to that format.

Comment: Could you create a working demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Or atleast show us your attempts of your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the miliseconds? You can always use the cast mysql method or convert the datetime object to unixtime then insert it in the mysql database. 
The code will be something like that

`INSERT into('timestampfield') VALUES(FROM_UNIXTIME('123456789'))`

I have done that acouple of times and it is great for correctly inserting timestamps in mysql fields.

First edit:

The unix timestamp format for moment.js is 'X' I belive this is the thing ypu are looking for.